# How to get text from PDF in Postman

Tags: javascript, pdf, postman

I need to extract text from a PDF received as response from a REST call in Postman

I googled how to do so and the only thing I found is that I should add an external library (PDFBox) in Postman, before trying to do so i wanted to ask if there's already something usefull in Postman to do what I need.

Thanks

Comment: there are just few libraries [integrated into Postman](https://learning.getpostman.com/docs/postman/scripts/postman_sandbox/). they all about XML, DOM and JSON, nothing specific to PDF(or any other binary format). Actually, you may try to work with response as a text string and utilize `String.prototype.match` but in general it's not guaranteed to be stable or flexible enough.

Comment: @skyboyer thanks for replying, but I think what you said won't work: using the PDF as string is pretty hard, it's encoded with "something" (i don't know what exactly) and contains several "random" chars (you know, like black squares with letter inside, upside down traingles, and so on…)